# Getting mysql row using curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl, row

Ok, so am trying to fetch mysql row from remote server database by posting 2 fields, member id and secret code

```
    if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mysite.com/get_user_info/index.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $data = array(
        'member_id' => $_GET['uid'],
        'secret' => 'secret'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

on the remote server /get_user_info

i have this

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE user_id = '$_POST[member_id]'");
    if($query){
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    }
print_r($row);
```

so am trying to fetch that user info row from mysql using curl, but i get just text

so how can i get usable php array, so i can do like `<?php echo $output['name']; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the remote server

```
echo serialize( $row );
```

in your first script

```
$array = unserialize( $output );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json

```
echo json_encode( $row );
```

and in the main script

```
$result=json_decode($output);
```

and to print use  `echo $result->name;`

Comment: Hey guys,
I am using the same ideas which you both had given, but i am not getting the solution....
Assume there are 2 locations(Delhi and Mumbai) and 2 databases(user and user).
I have written a SELECT query in delhi location, I am able to see the values which is in database.
My issue is i am trying to get the "delhi" locations value in mumbai server by using PHP CURL.
My UI will be in "MUMBAI"
From Mumbai location i need to get a data from delhi by using CURL GET method.